# Colima | Pushing ECR on AWS | failed to create LLB definition

Tags: docker, colima

Recently, docker desktop became paid software so I installed colima on MacOS

Now, when I am trying to push my code to AWS ECR using the following command:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region} | 
docker login --username AWS --password $(aws ecr 
get-login-password --region us-XXXX-1) XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-XXXX-1.amazonaws.com
```

I am getting this error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker- 
credential-desktop": executable file not found in $PATH, out: ``
```

After debugging, I found the main issue with the docker login, when I separately tried to login using "docker login", I am getting the same error.

I tried below command too but its not working:

```
colima nerdctl install --path "${HOME}/opt/bin/docker"
```

Can someone please suggest my next steps?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `credsStore` config from `~/.docker/config.json`.

It probably defines the credential store, and does not work:

```
"credsStore": "desktop",
```

[Ref](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/issues/52#issuecomment-956037291)

Answer (score -1):

I propose removing docker config file.

https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/issues/52#issuecomment-956036733

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.